# Xcode 12.5 deploy: An error occurred uploading to the App Store

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode12, xcode12.5

I get this error when deploying with Xcode 12.5 at the final step, while uploading:

```
App Store Connect Operation Error
An error occurred uploading to the App Store.
```

[image: gif of the error]

There's no further description nor can I find anything about it.

None of the fixes I found on older posts helped on this one.

When I execute `./iTMSTransporter -version` here `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/bin` I get this error:

`java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com/transporter/lib/osgibootstrapper.jar`

Not sure if that has anything to do with it...

How can I fix this or where can I find more information on this error?

Comment: I just asked a colleague of mine and it worked fine on his side. Then after two weeks it just started working again also on my side. No clue what has actually changed. Still no clue where to find logs or information about the errors. This is why I leave this question open.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue today. I have completely clean the Derived Data and other Developer cache files and started from the beginning (Archive + Upload). This solved the problem.

*Also, the first build failed because I ran out of disk space but this is maybe not related to the issue.*

Answer (score 0):

What works for me:

- Create archive with Xcode 12.5
- Quit Xcode 12.5
- Open Xcode 13
- Open Organizer and upload archive